# How prove this six $a+b+c+d+e+f|10\sum_{cyc}a^3-3\sum_{cyc}abc$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

When I do a  problem,I found this following maybe is right?

**conjecture**

> Let $a,b,c,d,e,f$ be postive integers,show that $$(a+b+c+d+e+f)|10\sum_{cyc} a^3-3\sum_{cyc} abc$$
>   or
>   $$(a+b+c+d+e+f)|[10(a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3+e^3+f^3)-3(abc+bcd+cde+def+efa+fab)]？$$

I  found if $a=b=c=d=e=f=1$,then is right and also it's right for $a=b=c=d=e=f$.

Answer (score 1):

Try $a=b=c=d=e=1$ and $f=2$. I think it's a counterexample.